# Rich Text Editor on Mobile Safari

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, mobile-safari

I'm trying to build a Web page that has a rich text editor.  Is it possible to use a rich text editor (such as [FCKEditor](http://fckeditor.net)) in Mobile Safari on the iPod Touch (or iPhone)?

All of the demos I tried worked perfectly but weren't editable (The keyboard doesn't appear)

**EDIT**: Does Mobile Safari support editable `IFRAMES` (or any equivalent) at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug with mobile Safari and rich text edit controls.  While trying to use the Zoho online word processor on my iPhone I found the below info
[from the Zoho FAQ](http://writer.zoho.com/public/help/zohowriterfaq/fullpage#iPhone).

> 3. I can't create or edit documents on my iPhone, the keyboard doesn't show up when opening iZoho on iPhone. What's the problem?
>
>    It is an issue with the iPhone as the safari browser doesn't seem to recognize the rich text editor area and hence the keyboard isn't appearing. This is not an iZoho specific problem as all the applications that use a WYSIWYG editor face the same issue. We hope that Apple will address this issue soon and come up with the next version of iPhone's Safari that supports rich text editing. As a workaround, we may give a plain text editor for users to edit/create their documents if this isn't corrected in Safari's next version.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a great, simple and complete rich text editor that you can modify and embed in your website like you want without any problems

Credit : [Making Content Editable: A simple but complete rich text editor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content#Example_A_simple_but_complete_rich_text_editor)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rich Text Editor</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var oDoc, sDefTxt;

function initDoc() {
  oDoc = document.getElementById("textBox");
  sDefTxt = oDoc.innerHTML;
  if (document.compForm.switchMode.checked) { setDocMode(true); }
}

function formatDoc(sCmd, sValue) {
  if (validateMode()) { document.execCommand(sCmd, false, sValue); oDoc.focus(); }
}

function validateMode() {
  if (!document.compForm.switchMode.checked) { return true ; }
  alert("Uncheck \"Show HTML\".");
  oDoc.focus();
  return false;
}

function setDocMode(bToSource) {
  var oContent;
  if (bToSource) {
    oContent = document.createTextNode(oDoc.innerHTML);
    oDoc.innerHTML = "";
    var oPre = document.createElement("pre");
    oDoc.contentEditable = false;
    oPre.id = "sourceText";
    oPre.contentEditable = true;
    oPre.appendChild(oContent);
    oDoc.appendChild(oPre);
    document.execCommand("defaultParagraphSeparator", false, "div");
  } else {
    if (document.all) {
      oDoc.innerHTML = oDoc.innerText;
    } else {
      oContent = document.createRange();
      oContent.selectNodeContents(oDoc.firstChild);
      oDoc.innerHTML = oContent.toString();
    }
    oDoc.contentEditable = true;
  }
  oDoc.focus();
}

function printDoc() {
  if (!validateMode()) { return; }
  var oPrntWin = window.open("","_blank","width=450,height=470,left=400,top=100,menubar=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes");
  oPrntWin.document.open();
  oPrntWin.document.write("<!doctype html><html><head><title>Print<\/title><\/head><body onload=\"print();\">" + oDoc.innerHTML + "<\/body><\/html>");
  oPrntWin.document.close();
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.intLink { cursor: pointer; }
img.intLink { border: 0; }
#toolBar1 select { font-size:10px; }
#textBox {
  width: 540px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
  padding: 12px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#textBox #sourceText {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 498px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
#editMode label { cursor: pointer; }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="initDoc();">
<form name="compForm" method="post" action="sample.php" onsubmit="if(validateMode()){this.myDoc.value=oDoc.innerHTML;return true;}return false;">
<input type="hidden" name="myDoc">
<div id="toolBar1">
<select onchange="formatDoc('formatblock',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
<option selected>- formatting -</option>
<option value="h1">Title 1 &lt;h1&gt;</option>
<option value="h2">Title 2 &lt;h2&gt;</option>
<option value="h3">Title 3 &lt;h3&gt;</option>
<option value="h4">Title 4 &lt;h4&gt;</option>
<option value="h5">Title 5 &lt;h5&gt;</option>
<option value="h6">Subtitle &lt;h6&gt;</option>
<option value="p">Paragraph &lt;p&gt;</option>
<option value="pre">Preformatted &lt;pre&gt;</option>
</select>
<select onchange="formatDoc('fontname',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
<option class="heading" selected>- font -</option>
<option>Arial</option>
<option>Arial Black</option>
<option>Courier New</option>
<option>Times New Roman</option>
</select>
<select onchange="formatDoc('fontsize',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
<option class="heading" selected>- size -</option>
<option value="1">Very small</option>
<option value="2">A bit small</option>
<option value="3">Normal</option>
<option value="4">Medium-large</option>
<option value="5">Big</option>
<option value="6">Very big</option>
<option value="7">Maximum</option>
</select>
<select onchange="formatDoc('forecolor',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
<option class="heading" selected>- color -</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
<select onchange="formatDoc('backcolor',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
<option class="heading" selected>- background -</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="toolBar2">
<img class="intLink" title="Clean" onclick="if(validateMode()&&confirm('Are you sure?')){oDoc.innerHTML=sDefTxt};" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQbAD04KTRLYzFRjlldZl9vj1dusY14WYODhpWIbbSVFY6O7IOXw5qbms+wUbCztca0ccS4kdDQjdTLtMrL1O3YitHa7OPcsd/f4PfvrvDv8Pv5xv///////////////////yH5BAEKAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAV84CeOZGmeaKqubMteyzK547QoBcFWTm/jgsHq4rhMLoxFIehQQSAWR+Z4IAyaJ0kEgtFoLIzLwRE4oCQWrxoTOTAIhMCZ0tVgMBQKZHAYyFEWEV14eQ8IflhnEHmFDQkAiSkQCI2PDC4QBg+OAJc0ewadNCOgo6anqKkoIQA7" />
<img class="intLink" title="Print" onclick="printDoc();" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
<img class="intLink" title="Undo" onclick="formatDoc('undo');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAOMKADljwliE33mOrpGjuYKl8aezxqPD+7/I19DV3NHa7P///////////////////////yH5BAEKAA8ALAAAAAAWABYAAARR8MlJq7046807TkaYeJJBnES4EeUJvIGapWYAC0CsocQ7SDlWJkAkCA6ToMYWIARGQF3mRQVIEjkkSVLIbSfEwhdRIH4fh/DZMICe3/C4nBQBADs=" />
<img class="intLink" title="Redo" onclick="formatDoc('redo');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIHAB1ChDljwl9vj1iE34Kl8aPD+7/I1////yH5BAEKAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAANKeLrc/jDKSesyphi7SiEgsVXZEATDICqBVJjpqWZt9NaEDNbQK1wCQsxlYnxMAImhyDoFAElJasRRvAZVRqqQXUy7Cgx4TC6bswkAOw==" />
<img class="intLink" title="Remove formatting" onclick="formatDoc('removeFormat')" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
<img class="intLink" title="Bold" onclick="formatDoc('bold');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAInhI+pa+H9mJy0LhdgtrxzDG5WGFVk6aXqyk6Y9kXvKKNuLbb6zgMFADs=" />
<img class="intLink" title="Italic" onclick="formatDoc('italic');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAKEDAAAAAF9vj5WIbf///yH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAAWABYAAAIjnI+py+0Po5x0gXvruEKHrF2BB1YiCWgbMFIYpsbyTNd2UwAAOw==" />
<img class="intLink" title="Underline" onclick="formatDoc('underline');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAKECAAAAAF9vj////////yH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAWABYAAAIrlI+py+0Po5zUgAsEzvEeL4Ea15EiJJ5PSqJmuwKBEKgxVuXWtun+DwxCCgA7" />
<img class="intLink" title="Left align" onclick="formatDoc('justifyleft');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAIghI+py+0Po5y02ouz3jL4D4JMGELkGYxo+qzl4nKyXAAAOw==" />
<img class="intLink" title="Center align" onclick="formatDoc('justifycenter');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAIfhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3jL4D4JOGI7kaZ5Bqn4sycVbAQA7" />
<img class="intLink" title="Right align" onclick="formatDoc('justifyright');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAIghI+py+0Po5y02ouz3jL4D4JQGDLkGYxouqzl43JyVgAAOw==" />
<img class="intLink" title="Numbered list" onclick="formatDoc('insertorderedlist');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIGAAAAADljwliE35GjuaezxtHa7P///////yH5BAEAAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAAM2eLrc/jDKSespwjoRFvggCBUBoTFBeq6QIAysQnRHaEOzyaZ07Lu9lUBnC0UGQU1K52s6n5oEADs=" />
<img class="intLink" title="Dotted list" onclick="formatDoc('insertunorderedlist');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIGAAAAAB1ChF9vj1iE33mOrqezxv///////yH5BAEAAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAAMyeLrc/jDKSesppNhGRlBAKIZRERBbqm6YtnbfMY7lud64UwiuKnigGQliQuWOyKQykgAAOw==" />
<img class="intLink" title="Quote" onclick="formatDoc('formatblock','blockquote');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQXAC1NqjFRjkBgmT9nqUJnsk9xrFJ7u2R9qmKBt1iGzHmOrm6Sz4OXw3Odz4Cl2ZSnw6KxyqO306K63bG70bTB0rDI3bvI4P///////////////////////////////////yH5BAEKAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAVP4CeOZGmeaKqubEs2CekkErvEI1zZuOgYFlakECEZFi0GgTGKEBATFmJAVXweVOoKEQgABB9IQDCmrLpjETrQQlhHjINrTq/b7/i8fp8PAQA7" />
<img class="intLink" title="Delete indentation" onclick="formatDoc('outdent');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIHAAAAADljwliE35GjuaezxtDV3NHa7P///yH5BAEAAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAAM2eLrc/jDKCQG9F2i7u8agQgyK1z2EIBil+TWqEMxhMczsYVJ3e4ahk+sFnAgtxSQDqWw6n5cEADs=" />
<img class="intLink" title="Add indentation" onclick="formatDoc('indent');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAOMIAAAAADljwl9vj1iE35GjuaezxtDV3NHa7P///////////////////////////////yH5BAEAAAgALAAAAAAWABYAAAQ7EMlJq704650B/x8gemMpgugwHJNZXodKsO5oqUOgo5KhBwWESyMQsCRDHu9VOyk5TM9zSpFSr9gsJwIAOw==" />
<img class="intLink" title="Hyperlink" onclick="var sLnk=prompt('Write the URL here','http:\/\/');if(sLnk&&sLnk!=''&&sLnk!='http://'){formatDoc('createlink',sLnk)}" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAOMKAB1ChDRLY19vj3mOrpGjuaezxrCztb/I19Ha7Pv8/f///////////////////////yH5BAEKAA8ALAAAAAAWABYAAARY8MlJq7046827/2BYIQVhHg9pEgVGIklyDEUBy/RlE4FQF4dCj2AQXAiJQDCWQCAEBwIioEMQBgSAFhDAGghGi9XgHAhMNoSZgJkJei33UESv2+/4vD4TAQA7" />
<img class="intLink" title="Cut" onclick="formatDoc('cut');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQSAB1ChBFNsRJTySJYwjljwkxwl19vj1dusYODhl6MnHmOrpqbmpGjuaezxrCztcDCxL/I18rL1P///////////////////////////////////////////////////////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAVu4CeOZGmeaKqubDs6TNnEbGNApNG0kbGMi5trwcA9GArXh+FAfBAw5UexUDAQESkRsfhJPwaH4YsEGAAJGisRGAQY7UCC9ZAXBB+74LGCRxIEHwAHdWooDgGJcwpxDisQBQRjIgkDCVlfmZqbmiEAOw==" />
<img class="intLink" title="Copy" onclick="formatDoc('copy');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQcAB1ChBFNsTRLYyJYwjljwl9vj1iE31iGzF6MnHWX9HOdz5GjuYCl2YKl8ZOt4qezxqK63aK/9KPD+7DI3b/I17LM/MrL1MLY9NHa7OPs++bx/Pv8/f///////////////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAWG4CeOZGmeaKqubOum1SQ/kPVOW749BeVSus2CgrCxHptLBbOQxCSNCCaF1GUqwQbBd0JGJAyGJJiobE+LnCaDcXAaEoxhQACgNw0FQx9kP+wmaRgYFBQNeAoGihCAJQsCkJAKOhgXEw8BLQYciooHf5o7EA+kC40qBKkAAAGrpy+wsbKzIiEAOw==" />
<img class="intLink" title="Paste" onclick="formatDoc('paste');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQUAD04KTRLY2tXQF9vj414WZWIbXmOrpqbmpGjudClFaezxsa0cb/I1+3YitHa7PrkIPHvbuPs+/fvrvv8/f///////////////////////////////////////////////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAWN4CeOZGmeaKqubGsusPvBSyFJjVDs6nJLB0khR4AkBCmfsCGBQAoCwjF5gwquVykSFbwZE+AwIBV0GhFog2EwIDchjwRiQo9E2Fx4XD5R+B0DDAEnBXBhBhN2DgwDAQFjJYVhCQYRfgoIDGiQJAWTCQMRiwwMfgicnVcAAAMOaK+bLAOrtLUyt7i5uiUhADs=" />
</div>
<div id="textBox" contenteditable="true"><p></p></div>
<p id="editMode"><input type="checkbox" name="switchMode" id="switchBox" hidden="hidden" onchange="setDocMode(this.checked);" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" hidden="hidden" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this at YUI Rich Text Editor page. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/

> The YUI Rich Text Editor does not currently support the iPhone or the
>   Nokia N95. Due to the interaction
>   model (specifically, the inability to
>   make a selection), the Editor will not
>   function as expected. In our tests, it
>   appears that the Apple and Nokia
>   Webkit implementations don't event
>   recognize the Editor as an editing
>   field — meaning that these browsers
>   are, at present, deliberately not
>   supporting the use of an iframe in
>   design mode.

"Inability to make a selection" would be a real problem in browser rich text editing.